# d3js How do I pass arguments to the Force Tick event?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a mature javascript application that uses requirejs and as such I cannot rely on global variables. I have d3js running in a proof of concept with my node networks but I have a problem with the Tick event listener in that I need to pass an object reference to it so that the Tick event handler can use properties on the sender object.

I currently have:

```
MyClass.prototype.SetupD3Force = function()
{    
      this.Force = d3.layout.force()
         .size([200, 200])
         .nodes([])
         .charge(-120)
         .on("tick", this.Tick);

// snip some code here
}

MyClass.prototype.Tick = function()
{
     // Need to get hold of the sender's object properties
}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
MyClass.prototype.SetupD3Force = function()
{    
      var width = 200;
      var height = 200;

      this.Force = d3.layout.force()
         .size([width, height])
         .nodes([])
         .charge(-120)
         .linkDistance(function(d) { 
             return d.value;
         })
         .on("tick", this.Tick, this); // Add a reference to the sender

// snip some code here
}

MyClass.prototype.Tick = function(sender)
{
     // Now I can get hold of my properties
    sender.MyProperties...
}
```

Am I missing something? How do I pass arguments into the Tick event?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "this" context inside the tick function is not already the sender, you can use the [.bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the outer context to the "this" context of Tick:

```
.on("tick", this.Tick.bind(this) )
```

And then use them later:

```
MyClass.prototype.Tick = function()
{
     console.log(this.width);
}
```

You can also pass further arguments that you want to be included as functional parameters. See the link above and also [this one from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now to link up the answer in the other forums I tried. :)